# Store html page in Mysql Database or File

Tags: mysql, html, database, file

Which is better and more efficient, storing saved html page in a database or storing it  as a file on the server and then use the database to reference and access the filename. The site is a small cms system, where a user can create his own html page then use a special link to access the page.

Comment: aksed many, many times already....

Comment: Sounds like an opportunity to try out a document-oriented (non-relational) database like Mongo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's more efficient to use mysql. You also have more control on how you can manipulate the data.